# How to find root cause of Application Crash in Windbg?

Tags: crash, windbg

I have an application which crashes upon a specific action taken by the user. For instance, when I click on a specific button in the application, it crashes.

So, I attached windbg to this application and then performed the same operation which would trigger the crash.

When the crash happened, debugger shows the following output:

```
0:001> g
ModLoad: 04530000 04565000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.DLL
ModLoad: 72430000 7246c000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll
ModLoad: 723e0000 723e5000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wshtcpip.dll
(10b0.1e9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(10b0.1c94): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(10b0.1c94): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=00000000 ebx=040ee7e0 ecx=00000003 edx=00000000 esi=005c7630 edi=00400000
eip=770715de esp=040ee7cc ebp=040eece4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!ZwRaiseException+0x12:
770715de 83c404          add     esp,4
```

I want to analyze the above output to find out the root cause of this exception. Maybe, I could report it to the developer of this application then? But for my understanding I would like to grasp this output.

I can see that the exe loads the 3 dlls, ws2_32.dll, mswsock.dll and wshtcpip.dll when I click on that button probably because it uses functions exported from these loaded modules.

There are 2 first chance exceptions with the exception code: e06d7363 which is the exception code according to Visual C++ Compiler.

I am not sure why the second chance exception comes and what's exactly going on there?

Below is the view of call stack at this point in the debugger,

```
0:001> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
03a4e7cc 7706014d ntdll!ZwRaiseException+0x12
03a4e7cc 00000000 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0x29
```

I pressed g again in the debugger to allow the application to handle the exception and this is the output in debugger,

```
0:001> g
WARNING: Continuing a non-continuable exception
(114c.390): Unknown exception - code 00000000 (first chance)
(114c.390): Unknown exception - code 00000000 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=00000000 ebx=03a4e318 ecx=83ee0000 edx=026ce8b8 esi=007073e0 edi=00400000
eip=770715de esp=03a4e304 ebp=03a4ece4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!ZwRaiseException+0x12:
770715de 83c404          add     esp,4
```

So, looks like an unhandled exception by the application?

---

Here are the details. I have used the kv command to show the parameters on the stack. Hope this information helps you to troubleshoot.

```
0:001> g
ModLoad: 040a0000 040d5000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.DLL
ModLoad: 72430000 7246c000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll
ModLoad: 723e0000 723e5000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wshtcpip.dll
(193c.1810): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(193c.1810): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=00000000 ebx=02c1e7e0 ecx=00000003 edx=00000000 esi=007073e0 edi=00400000
eip=770715de esp=02c1e7cc ebp=02c1ece4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!ZwRaiseException+0x12:
770715de 83c404          add     esp,4
0:001> kv
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
02c1e7cc 7706014d 02c1e7e0 02c1e830 00000000 ntdll!ZwRaiseException+0x12 (FPO: [3,0,0])
02c1e7cc 00000000 02c1e7e0 02c1e830 00000000 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0x29     (FPO: [2,0,0]) (CONTEXT @ 0000000c)
0:001> g
WARNING: Continuing a non-continuable exception
(193c.1810): Unknown exception - code 00000000 (first chance)
(193c.1810): Unknown exception - code 00000000 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=00000000 ebx=02c1e318 ecx=e04b0000 edx=0096e8b8 esi=007073e0 edi=00400000
eip=770715de esp=02c1e304 ebp=02c1ece4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!ZwRaiseException+0x12:
770715de 83c404          add     esp,4
```

Comment: A common practice is to use Debug Diag, ADPlus, or other dump capture commands/utilities to capture crash dumps and then analyze in WinDbg (beginning with analyze -v).

Answer (score 4):

A couple of comments

- Thread (10b0.1e9c) got an exception and was handling the exception
- Thread (10b0.1c94) did not handle the exception. To analyze this we need to 
  look at the stack trace. However the stack trace is incomplete and should have
  been created with the kv command to show the parameters on the stack.
- The second output is from a different process: 114c. So its inconsistent.

To analyze this we need the kv output when the exception is raised and then dump the exception record. Please provide the information and then I can show how to dump the exception record.

Based on the posted results run: ".exr 02c1e830"